# When deleting a user do the entries they created also get deleted?

Tags: entries, users

We had an instance where a user deleted an admin and it seemed to delete the content that user had created. Is this currently how Craft works? If so is there a way around that without having to change every entry's author. Or suggestion adding a prompt to warn user of content being deleted and to just suspend them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, yes, that's how it works.

It's on our list to 1) Add a prompt warning what's about to happen and 2) Add options as to what you want to do with that author's current content (assign to a different user, delete, etc.).

**Update:**

As of [Craft 2.3](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615), when a user's account is deleted you'll be prompted what you want to do with their content.

Comment: Any update on the reassignment feature? We had a client make the user-delete mistake today and had to roll back the database.

Comment: None yet, @JDH.  I'll see what we can do about this for 2.3, though.

Comment: ["When deleting a user account, it is now possible to transfer that user’s content to another user."](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615)